# fwrite() performance drop

Tags: c, windows

My commands-line C-application for Windows uses fwrite() to continuously dump received data to 1 GB files on an SSD drive. The data comes from a PCIe card in chunks of about 16 KB, which is the data count I use when calling fwrite().

Under these circumstances, each fwrite() call usually takes less than 100 us (measured using Windows performance counter) **but there are outliers taking 2 or more seconds to complete**, causing buffer overflows in the PCIe card. What's the cause of these sporadic performance drops? Is there anything I can do to prevent them from happening?

**Update #1**: part of the problem seems to be caused by the SSD drive. When dumping to a regular, mechanical HDD, the outliers are in the order of 100 msecs (instead of 1000s of msecs).

**Update #2**: it seems that the fwrite() slowdown occurs after writing the first 1.5 GB of data. When dumping to 1 GB files, the slowdown occurs in the middle of the second file. When using 512 MB files, it's after the 3rd file. When using 256 MB files, it's after the 6th file.

Comment: How frequently do you see those outliers? It's always one or the other, no intermediate values?

Comment: Sounds like a buffering effect to me. Try adding a `fflush()` after each `fwrite()`. If the outliers are gone then the fast `fwrite()` calls simply write to a buffer in memory and the long `fwrite()` calls write the entire buffer to your drive.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you properly open the file in binary mode (`"wb"`) ? IO in text mode can exhibit weird behavior.

Comment: @ElderBug yes, I opened the file in binary mode

Comment: @LukasThomsen calling fflush() after fwrite() does not solve the problem. I'm still seeing these huge outliers, especially when starting to write into a new file (after closing a full 1 GB file and creating a new one).

Comment: Is it possible that the hardware might be to blame?

Comment: I've experienced a lot of strange effects with flash devices and closing or flushing files (but not on Windows). Does not closing the file make a difference? ... Anyway I fear that the cause might be the file system of Windows combined with the bad block management of the device itself.

Comment: fwrite() perf falls off a cliff when the file system cache fills up to capacity.  Which can fill up when you firehose the disk and fwrite faster than the device can perform the writes.  It then has to wait for the physical write to occur so space becomes available again.  Delays at 1.5 GB would be typical for a machine with 4 GB of RAM.  Buying more RAM is a simple workaround but not a firehose fix, it will just take longer for the delay to occur.  FlushFileBuffers() might distribute the delays better.

Comment: @HansPassant when opening the file in "commit" mode using fopen(filename, "wbc"), I'm seeing regular FlushBuffersFile every 2 MB. But the performance is abysmal, about 7 MB/s.

Comment: You need to go shopping, we can't do that for you.  Do disable anti-malware before you whip out the car keys.

Comment: suggest learning exactly how harddrives and SSDs actually work.  Until then, the code will need to do a combination of heavy (double) buffering and throttle the data rate.  One possibility is to use SSDs that are at least 'speed 10' to help minimize delays

Comment: Note: calling `fflush()` will not eliminate the delays that are inherent in the external I/O devices.  All that will do is make sure the program does not continue until after the data has been written to the device

Answer (score 1):

Stealing [something](http://electronicdesign.com/memory/fundamentals-flash-memory-storage):

> Flash memory uses an erase-write cycle. The erase essentially sets the
>   memory to all 1s. Writing sets bits to 0, and it’s possible to write
>   different data as long as existing 1s are changed to 0s. Flash file
>   systems can take advantage of this feature because it permits
>   operations to be performed without a long and electrically expensive
>   erase cycle.

With an SSD, you probably aren't using a flash file system. My guess is that periodically you need to pause writing while the SSD controller frees up space by erasing some sectors.

Comment: It seems that the SSD is part of the problem. When dumping the file to a regular hard disk drive, I'm still seeing outliers in the range of 100 msec but nowhere near the 1000s of msecs I'm having with the SSD.